# Cambiar la traducción de "origen" a "fuente" o "código fuente"

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, traducciones

Cuando se revisa el historial de ediciones de una publicación, por ejemplo

https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/73/revisions

La palabra ***origen*** creo que debe ser traducida mejor como ***fuente*** o ***código fuente***

[image: Screenshot de revisión]

Comment: Creo que "código fuente" no es la mejor traducción ya que se refiere a la versión original del _post_ editado.

Comment: @Zero Te equivocas, el link te lleva a una página con texto plano del **código fuente en markdown** de la revisión actual. Si quieres ver la revisión original solo has scroll hacia abajo. Creo que la confusión es porque la revisión 3 y la 1 son idénticas pero puedes probar en otros posts

Comment: Tienes razón, en el _tooltip_ te indica, perdón por no chequearlo.  Si te fijas dice "ver el texto de esta modificación sin formato".

Comment: No te puedo "linkear" con @ ¿será por la **Ñ** ?

Comment: Estaría bien si este tipo de cosas se publican aquí: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83/sugerencias-de-mejora-en-las-traducciones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Se ha cambiado a "código fuente"!

Comment: Gracias Juan, ya vi el cambio online